# InvalidProtocolBufferException when trying to write to HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, protocol-buffers

Here is my code:

```
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml"));
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://localhost:8020"),conf);
        Path path = new Path(hdfsDestination);
        FSDataOutputStream outputStream = fs.create(path);
```

The hdfsDestination is /user/msknapp/insurance, Here is the output:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).; Host Details : local host is: "localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "localhost":8020; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1351)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.create(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1382)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:905)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:772)
    at knapp.hdfs.importer.insurance.InsuranceIO.writeToHdfsAsAvro(InsuranceIO.java:68)
    at knapp.hdfs.importer.insurance.InsuranceIO.writeFileToHdfsAsAvro(InsuranceIO.java:51)
    at knapp.hdfs.importer.ImporterCommandLine.run(ImporterCommandLine.java:72)
    at knapp.hdfs.importer.ImporterCommandLine.main(ImporterCommandLine.java:61)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:89)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readTag(CodedInputStream.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.<init>(RpcHeaderProtos.java:1398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.<init>(RpcHeaderProtos.java:1362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto$1.parsePartialFrom(RpcHeaderProtos.java:1492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto$1.parsePartialFrom(RpcHeaderProtos.java:1487)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:200)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:241)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:253)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:259)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.parseDelimitedFrom(RpcHeaderProtos.java:2364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:996)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:891)
```

I have CDH4.8 running in pseudo-distributed mode:

```
[msknapp@localhost conf]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/msknapp
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - msknapp supergroup          0 2014-01-01 10:22 /user/msknapp/input
drwxr-xr-x   - msknapp supergroup          0 2014-01-01 10:35 /user/msknapp/output23
[msknapp@localhost conf]$ hadoop fs -ls /user
Found 1 items
drwxrwxrwx   - msknapp supergroup          0 2014-01-01 10:35 /user/msknapp
[msknapp@localhost conf]$ whereis hadoop
hadoop: /usr/bin/hadoop /etc/hadoop /usr/lib/hadoop /usr/share/man/man1/hadoop.1.gz
```

I'm using CentOS 6.4 if that matters.  I am able to put data into HDFS from the command line just fine, but not from code for some reason.  Can somebody please tell me why I can't write to HDFS with my code?

Comment: Is your program build with same version of jar files that are used in CDH4.8,This issue may happen due to version miss match in Hadoop RPC call using Protcbuffer.

Comment: Good point renZzz, I am using maven to manage dependencies, but all of my CDH4.8 was installed using yum, and they must have came from cloudera's yum repository.  In maven I have groupId=org.apache.hadoop, artifactId=hadoop-client, and version=2.2.0.  That in turn has transitive dependencies on everything else I need.  Do you think I should instead use a system dependency?  Or maybe I should find the hadoop jar on my system, and see what groupId, artifactId, and version it specifies in its META-DATA's maven info.

Comment: I think the solution is to use cloudera's maven repository, and the convention is to append '-cdh4.5.0' to the jar's version so it uses cloudera's patched jar, the one that will work with the installed CDH cluster.  Here is the website that explains it all:  http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH-Version-and-Packaging-Information/cdhvd_topic_8.html?scroll=concept_dlf_kq1_bm_unique_3

Comment: Yes it seems like using cloudera CDH4 Maven Repository is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same exception and I found out that a few dependencies were missing, I only had hadoop-core but needed a few more. When I added these it worked:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0-cdh4.3.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0-cdh4.3.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: yeah I just add a dependency on hadoop-client, it has transitive dependencies on the rest, including the ones you listed.  I have not taken the time to see what the difference is yet, maybe if I get a chance I will post back.

Comment: I got the same exception and have already all dependencies you mentioned. It's possible some missing dependencies are causing this, but not the ones you listed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to write in this path " /usr/msknapp/insurance" but show permission this path "/user/msknapp"!

Comment: I think you may have assumed that /user/msknapp/insurance is a directory, it is not, in fact it does not exist.  My intent is for that to be a file, and for that file to be created by the fs.create command.  I was showing you the permission of /user/msknapp to prove that all users have permission to write (i.e. create a file) in that directory.

Comment: /usr and /user is different path. /usr exist on your file system and /user exist in HDFS. you say The hdfsDestination is /usr/msknapp/insurance and I think you forgotten 'e' in path!

Comment: sorry it was supposed to be /user, I fixed it in my original post now.  When I did all the commands though, I was correctly using /user, I just wrote it wrong in my description above.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be using incompatible version of protobuf-java-X.jar. Please check the protobuf jar version for building your application and what is used in CDH4.8